# Regarding create a NTL class type

Tags: c++

Thanks for looking

I trying to create a class

```
long lPrime,lGenerator;
    lPrime = atol(vOut[1].c_str());
ZZ alicePrime;
    alicePrime = new ZZ(99999,lPrime);
```

I not sure what does INIT_VAL_TYPE asking me to input.

I got this error:

```
UDPEchoClient.cpp:85:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘NTL::ZZ::ZZ(int, long int&)’
UDPEchoClient.cpp:85:34: note: candidates are:
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:113:1: note: NTL::ZZ::ZZ(NTL::ZZ&, NTL::INIT_TRANS_TYPE)
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:113:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘NTL::ZZ&’
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:176:8: note: NTL::ZZ::ZZ(NTL::INIT_VAL_TYPE, double)
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:176:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘NTL::INIT_VAL_TYPE {aka const NTL::INIT_VAL_STRUCT&}’
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:180:8: note: NTL::ZZ::ZZ(NTL::INIT_VAL_TYPE, float)
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:180:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘NTL::INIT_VAL_TYPE {aka const NTL::INIT_VAL_STRUCT&}’
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:172:8: note: NTL::ZZ::ZZ(NTL::INIT_VAL_TYPE, const char*)
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:172:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘NTL::INIT_VAL_TYPE {aka const NTL::INIT_VAL_STRUCT&}’
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:61:1: note: NTL::ZZ::ZZ(NTL::INIT_VAL_TYPE, unsigned int)
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:61:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘NTL::INIT_VAL_TYPE {aka const NTL::INIT_VAL_STRUCT&}’
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:60:1: note: NTL::ZZ::ZZ(NTL::INIT_VAL_TYPE, long unsigned int)
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:60:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘NTL::INIT_VAL_TYPE {aka const NTL::INIT_VAL_STRUCT&}’
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:58:1: note: NTL::ZZ::ZZ(NTL::INIT_VAL_TYPE, int)
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:58:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘NTL::INIT_VAL_TYPE {aka const NTL::INIT_VAL_STRUCT&}’
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:57:1: note: NTL::ZZ::ZZ(NTL::INIT_VAL_TYPE, long int)
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:57:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘NTL::INIT_VAL_TYPE {aka const NTL::INIT_VAL_STRUCT&}’
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:49:1: note: NTL::ZZ::ZZ(const NTL::ZZ&)
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:49:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:37:1: note: NTL::ZZ::ZZ(NTL::INIT_SIZE_TYPE, long int)
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:37:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘NTL::INIT_SIZE_TYPE {aka const NTL::INIT_SIZE_STRUCT&}’
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:33:1: note: NTL::ZZ::ZZ()
/sw/include/NTL/ZZ.h:33:1: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly `new` is wrong. You aren't allocating an object, you are constructing an object.

Secondly, assuming I'm reading the header file right, and assuming I understand what you are trying to do, you just want

```
ZZ alicePrime(INIT_VAL, lPrime);
```

`INTI_VAL` is just a constant that forces the compile to choose the constructor that gives `alicePrime` an initial value, instead of, say, an initial bit size.

NTL documentation is poor.